# Angular and Laravel CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issues

Tags: angular, laravel, cors, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

I have been woking on a Angular (Client) and Laravel (API) application for the past few months locally on my dev machines without any issues. A few days ago i uploaded the applications (client and api) to the server and all of the sudden i started to get CORS errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.domain.pt/api/login' from
>   origin 'https://client.domain.pt' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

In the beginning of the development i also got those erros because i was using different local domains for both client and api (client.localhost and api.localhost) and ended up solving the issues adding a CORS middleware to my Laravel API:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //apply cors only to api routes
    if (Request::segment(1) == 'api') {

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding, X-Login-Origin',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true'
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod("OPTIONS")) {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);

        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
    } else {
        $response = $next($request);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

All the routes are using the CORS middleware. When the app tries to post to the login api (/api/login) it doesn't even enter the CORS middleware.

Why is this working locally and not in the server?

Comment: How you have registered this middleware? route wise or globally ?

Comment: Both globally and route wise. I was desperate :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my issue. Since my custom CORS middleware isn't being called, i added custom headers to my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>        
    <!-- SOLVES CORS ISSUES -->
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding, X-Login-Origin" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
   <!-- /SOLVES CORS ISSUES -->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Its the most appropriate solution, but i'm going to use it for now. 
If anyone has any other solution, rather than force custom headers, please reply.

**UPDATE:**

Temporary solution for Apache. Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding, X-Login-Origin, responseType"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below help and reference link for help:

> You can check CORS Middleware for Laravel  package or below link:

[Angular and Laravel CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issues](https://therichpost.com/question/angular-6-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)